# Replace occurances of a contents in variable with a string using replace method

Tags: javascript, replace

I am facing trouble in getting the all occurances of pattern of a string replaced with another string.My string looks like this

```
"<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.Rule<SPAN> <A style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline" id=RULE#I#000002$000000 class=anchorTag NAME:RULE#I#000002$000000?>xxxx</A>&nbsp;
<SCRIPT>function show(id){document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";}function hide(id){document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";}</SCRIPT>
<NOBR><SPAN style="CURSOR: hand" id=RULE#T#000002$000000NAME:RULE#T#000002$000000 onmouseover="show('RULE#T#000002$000000')" onmouseout="hide('RULE#T#000002$000000',event)" onclick="button_click('RULE#T#000002$000000');" valign="top"><IMG style="VISIBILITY: hidden; CURSOR: hand" id=RULE#T#000002$000000 title="Maintain Rule Title" align=middle src="../../IRM/GBRFFNM/images/text_icon.png" width=12 height=12></SPAN></NOBR><NOBR><SPAN style="CURSOR: hand" id=RULE#A#000002$000000NAME:RULE#A#000002$000000 onmouseover="show('RULE#A#000002$000000')" onmouseout="hide('RULE#A#000002$000000')" onclick="javascript:button_click('RULE#A#000002$000000',event)" valign="top"><IMG style="VISIBILITY: visible; CURSOR: hand" id=RULE#A#000002$000000 title="Add Rule" align=middle src="../../IRM/GBRFFNM/plus.gif" width=12 height=12></SPAN></NOBR></SPAN></TD>"
```

I need to replace the id RULE#A#000002$000000 with RULE#A#000003$000000.These ids are dynamic.I searched stack over flow and found that i need to create regular expression.Here is what i did..

```
var lv_html = parent.innerHTML; ///Contains the string abovwe

  var array = _eleid.split('#');
  var array1 = array[2].split('$');
  lv_id = array1[0] + '$';  // = RULE#A#000002$000000
  var replace_id = stmt_cntr + '$' ; // = RULE#A#000003$000000
  var  html1 =  lv_html.replace(new RegExp( lv_id , 'g'), replace_id);
```

but i found this was not working. Did i miss something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the string you're creating your regex from:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

... new RegExp( escapeRegExp(lv_id) , 'g') ...
```

Your string contains a `$`, which has a special meaning (end of line) in a regex.